# Combined data from multiple sheets into one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have data within cells C21:F40 on multiple sheets (excluded merge and loadfile sheets) that I want to copy onto one  master sheet (Merge). Once the data has been consolidated on the Merge sheet I then want to sum col c and remove any duplicates.

[Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V292q.jpg)

I've looked everywhere and cannot find anything that can do the above so any help would be greatly appreciated

Option Explicit
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

```
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long

'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"

'Set references up-front
Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!
lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!

'Set the initial destination range
Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)

'Loop through all sheets
For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
    If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" Then

        'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
        lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

        'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
        With wksSrc
            Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, lngLastCol))
            rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
        End With

        'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
        lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)

    End If

Next wksSrc
```

End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("B1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("B1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedColNum = lng
End Function

Answer (score 0):

Some of this post is vague to exactly what you need, but I think what you are looking for can be found here:

[Merge Data From Multiple Sheets Onto One Sheet](https://danwagner.co/how-to-combine-data-from-multiple-sheets-into-a-single-sheet/)

However, if you are not familiar with VBA, even this website, followed exactly may be difficult.

Comment: Thanks Division. . One thing I'm confused about is how do a) exclude more than one sheet within the script. also how do I amend the source copy one column across. As the data I want to copy from each sheet is in cells C21:F40